# Statement gets skipped when correct input is given the first time but not after a re-prompt?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with a statement that gets skipped, and also an infinite loop which I can't figure out why it's infinite since it appears to end when the correct input has been given.

Here's a fiddle so you can understand what's happening easier: http://jsfiddle.net/z03ffn2j/

In the else statement I'm running a while loop that runs as long as the current player tries to ask himself the question in the askPlayer function. So if a player is named "chris" and that player enters "chris", the prompt comes up again.

All good and well, but.. When I don't type "chris" the first time and instead type, let's say "tommy", it skips the `var card` statement which asks for a value. However, when I enter "chris" the first time, it re-prompts cuz it's myself, and then I enter "tommy", it doesn't skip the `var code` statement. So my question is, why does it skip it when I enter a correct name the first time, but not if I first enter a false name and then a correct one?

```
var playerArray = []; //Contains player objects
var turn = 0; //Keeps track of whose turn it is

function askPlayer() {
    var askedPlayer = prompt('Which player do you want to ask?');
    return askedPlayer;
}

//While the pairCount is less than 13(maximum possible pairs)
while (pairCount < maxPairs) {

    if (playerArray[turn].totalCards == 0) {
    drawCard(); 
    }

    else {
        var wrongInput = true;
        var player = askPlayer();

        while (wrongInput) {

            if (player === playerArray[turn].name) {
                player = askPlayer();
                if (player != playerArray[turn].name) {
                    wrongInput = false;    
                }
            }
        }

    var card = askCard(player); //<--- This statement gets skipped
}

pairCount = 13; //Prevents infinite loop for now
turn++;

if (turn == playerNum - 1) { //If everyone has made their turn, reset to player1 again
    turn = 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a player name that isn't equal to the current turn's player name, you'll enter an infinite loop.

You have:

```
var wrongInput = true;
var player = askPlayer();
while (wrongInput) {
    if (player === playerArray[turn].name) {
        player = askPlayer();
        if (player != playerArray[turn].name) {
            wrongInput = false;
        }
    }
}
var card = askCard(player);
```

As you can see, the 1st time the loop is entered, `wrongInput` will be `true`. Assuming the player's names are `a` and `b` respectively and you answered `b` to `askPlayer()`, the 1st `if` statement will be false (`player` is `b` and `playerArray[0].name` is `a`).

Since you have no other code inside the loop, it'll jump right to the `while (wrongInput)` evaluation... and now you're stuck in a never-ending loop.

So, it seems you forgot one closing bracket after `player = askPlayer()`.

To fix it, instead of:

```
if (player === playerArray[turn].name) {
    player = askPlayer();
    if (player != playerArray[turn].name) {
        wrongInput = false;
    }
}
```

... write:

```
if (player === playerArray[turn].name) {
    player = askPlayer();
}
if (player != playerArray[turn].name) {
    wrongInput = false;
}
```

Or, better yet:

```
if (player === playerArray[turn].name) {
    player = askPlayer();
} else {
    wrongInput = false;
}
```

Comment: How could I forget the else statement.. Was staring at my code for so long without noticing it, haha. Sometimes I swear I'm mentally handicapped.. Thanks for your answer man, appreciate it.